# Process.Start(URL) using only 1 tab

Tags: c#, url, process.start

I am sorry if I am posting a common question, if thats what this is. I am not sure how to look this up to find a good answer as to how to do this though. I have searched for days about this, and with no answers, my last resort is to ask :)

I have this C# application I have been working on for a while off and on these past few years. The most recent request is to use the Link labels I am using to show info, and to bring a URL up in a browser. I am using this:

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URL);

The trouble is, I feel this is going to cause issues since hundreds of clicks is a possibility, I want to make it so that it only uses 1 tab, instead of opening new tabs every time another link is clicked. Is this possible? Am I using the wrong process to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think thiw will be possible using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`
Because this method just ask the OS to start the program associated with the Uri passed as an argument. Think of it this way : the OS have no means of knowing if one browser can make a tab, and neither how to tell it to.
I'd look into the browser parameters

Comment: I almost feel that way too. Thats why I am wondering if there is something else I should use in place of. I have searched so much, and have not had much luck getting the answers on any forums yet :)

Comment: Unless you target a specific browser like @kawa suggested, i don't think there is a solution available

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the usage of IE, you can do this:

```
Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE","–framemerging URL");
```

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Great thought, but unless I did it wrong, it opens a new window each time, not doing tabs atleast, but still not quite what I am looking for. Thanks for such a fast response about it :)